# Docker : crontab -l and crontab -e not returning anything

Tags: docker, ubuntu, cron, debian

N.B. Below is from within Docker container, base image of Python-3.7.2-slim.

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.7.2-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron && apt-get -y install nano
```

So, I've installed `cron` via apt-get. Verified running with `service cron status`:

```
[ ok ] cron is running.
```

However, the commands `crontab -l` and `crontab -e` returns zilch, nothing:

[image]

I have verified that my `cron` tasks are working from the command line inside the container.

The two commands are as follows:

```
* * * * * python /usr/src/app/manage.py organisation_benefit_aggregates --aggregate >> /usr/src/logs/cron.log 2>&1 && echo "Organisation Benefit Aggregator Ran Sucessfully" >> /usr/src/logs/cron.log
* * * * * python /usr/src/app/manage.py organisation_survey_aggregates --aggregate >> /usr/src/logs/cron.log 2>&1 && echo "Organisation Survey Aggregator Ran Sucessfully" >> /usr/src/logs/cron.log
```

`cron.log` has permissions `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root`. But is completely empty.

Running either command, e.g., `python /usr/src/app/manage.py organisation_survey_aggregates --aggregate` is verified to be working by manual inspection of data changes.

*However, via the cron - nothing is working.* There is no change in data, etc via manual inspection.

**Q's**:

Why are the commands `crontab -l` and `crontab -e` not working?

How do I go about diagnosing why the cron isn't running as specified?

Why is DevOps on Docker such a ball ache?

Comment: A Docker container isn't a VM; it usually runs _one_ process.  You shouldn't expect commands like `service` to work usefully in a Docker context, and if the one process it runs is a shell, it's not going to do anything else.  Running cron on the host is often the most straightforward path.

Comment: @DavidMaze This is a little bit jargon heavy and a bit "you shouldn't just do this"...please expand.

Comment: To pick on `service`: it “doesn’t work” for two big reasons.  The first is that a container runs one process, and when that process is done, the container exits; since `service` returns immediately, `CMD ["service", "x", "start"]` results in a container that always exits with status 0.  If your `service` (or especially `systemctl`) depends on an init process, containers usually don’t run a dedicated init (and especially not systemd) so this just doesn’t work.

Comment: “It usually runs one process”, because that’s how Docker works: a container wraps exactly one process, and when that process exits the container exits.  Usually the container main process is the thing you want to run and you rely on Docker as a kind of supervisor.  There are workarounds that use a dedicated supervisor as the container process, and hacks that use background processes in shell scripts, but usually the best practice is to run multiple processes in multiple containers.

Comment: @DavidMaze I think for me - all I really want to know is why does the cron within the actively running container behave like this. The above as you describe is extremely unhelpful - surely they can see that you might need to run the cron service and a web service from within the same container? Massive limitation and will likely mean I can not use containers. If there's a way to use cron tasks within a container, I would entertain an answer. Otherwise, your comments aren't that helpful to tackling my issue.